# Does RStudio auto generated "Package with Rcpp" allow Rcpp modules?

Tags: rstudio, rcpp

I was trying to expose my C++ class through Rcpp by building a package. It seems that module is not allowed in RStudio auto-generated template. For example, if we compare the NAMESPACE file generated by `Rcpp.package.skeleton(myPackage, module=TRUE)` and by RStudio, `importFrom(Rcpp, loadModule)` is not in the RStudio NAMESPACE file. Did I miss something? How can I enable RStudio to generate module allowed package template?

Here is a minimal example to show my C++ codes in case someone would like to try it in RStudio

```
class Student{
private:
  double age;
  double GPA;
public:
  Student(double age_, double GPA_):age(age_),GPA(GPA_){}

  double sum(double x, double myGPA){
    GPA = myGPA;
    return GPA + x;
  }
  double times(double x, double myage){
    age = myage;
    return age*GPA*x;
  }
};


RCPP_MODULE(my_module){
  class_<Student>("Student")
  .constructor<double, double>()
  .method("sum", &Student::sum)
  .method("times",&Student::times);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In very, very short: No. Or maybe "sort of; not completely".

A bit more expanded:  The auto-package stub creates a working basic Rcpp package.  But eg not an RcppArmadillo package (and this has bitten people before).

And we *do include a complete example* for Rcpp Modules in the package [in this directory](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/tree/master/inst/unitTests/testRcppModule) (which is used by the unit tests) so you may have to do a few steps by hand if you go that route.

You can also try the helper function `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` with the option `module=TRUE` which the other formal option.

So in sum you cannot reasonably expect the RStudio GUI to support every available permutation.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, RStudio is limited in generating Rcpp project types for this version (1.0). Per a [PR](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/pull/908), custom package templates are incoming!

To get around this limitation, try the following:

1. Close all open projects.
2. Run the following: `Rcpp.package.skeleton("myPackage", module=TRUE)`
3. `New Project` -> `From Existing Directory` or use `devtools::use_rstudio()` to generate the `.Rproj`.

#### Edit 1

Per the comment, what really is happening is two fold:

First, the module definition needs to be updated to be:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

class Student{
private:
    double age;
    double GPA;
public:
    Student(double age_, double GPA_):age(age_),GPA(GPA_){}

    double sum(double x, double myGPA){
        GPA = myGPA;
        return GPA + x;
    }
    double times(double x, double myage){
        age = myage;
        return age*GPA*x;
    }
};


RCPP_MODULE(my_module){
    using namespace Rcpp ; // Added (if not done globally)

    class_<Student>("Student")
    .constructor<double, double>()
    .method("sum", &Student::sum, "Sum")      // Add some documentation (optional)
    .method("times",&Student::times, "Times");
}
```

Next, in some *R* code file add:

```
loadModule("my_module", TRUE)
```

Build and Reload

Then, you have:

```
s <- new( Student, 1, 2 )
s$sum(2,4)
# [1] 6
s$times(5,6)
# [1] 120
```

Comment: We are thinking that same thing! But it doesn't work. It seems that this method produced some errors in RStudio. Could you please try it and see if you have some further idea to fix the error?

Comment: Your question is a completely separate issue that you are running into... You are not looking to build a project shell, but you are seeking instead to have RStudio build the automagic for module loads.

Comment: Dear @drdombe: At some point you have to put a little bit of effort in yourself, not unlike what I just had to tell on the BH issue where you also seemed to be confused about basics.  Start simple, do some reading, go from there.  I would use fewer tools to get a better handle on actual required steps.

Comment: Thank you so much, Dirk. You are right. I am so new to these and humbled to learn a lot from you and many others. Thank you for your patience spending time on answering my naive questions, although I did spend many hours to figure it out. Hopefully, with your help, I can be more capable and help others someday. Many people really appreciate your work and there are more people (including patients) are benefiting from what you have provided!